# Replace text link with image using php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

```
   l(t('Edit'), 'node/' . $node->nid . '/webform/components/' . $cid, array('query' => drupal_get_destination())),
```

I'd like to be able to replace the word "Edit" with an image instead, however when I put an image src in there it shows up as text.  Is there a different function I should be using?

I'm using Drupal as my framework.

Thanks ffrom a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button should have its own class, for example, `action_button` or an id such as `edit_button`. Now use CSS to hide the text and use a background image in its place as shown below:

```
.action_button, #edit_button {

  /* Hide Text */
  text-indent: -9999px;

  display: block;
  background: url('edit_button.png') no-repeat;

  /* Set width and height equal to the size of your image */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Change your code with below and use above CSS:

```
l(t('Edit'), 'node/'.$node->nid.'/webform/components/'.$cid, array('attributes' => array('id' => array('edit_button')), 'query' => drupal_get_destination()));
```

---

**EDIT 2 [FINAL]:**

Passing `html` as `TRUE` to `array parameter` of `l()` method can make us able to use `first parameter` as `img` tag instead of just text for display as link:

```
l('<img src="edit_button.png" alt="Edit" />', 'node/'.$node->nid.'/webform/components/'.$cid, array('query' => drupal_get_destination(), 'html' => 'TRUE'));
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal, however the text doesn't have it's own class set in Webform module on Drupal - I thought it would just be easier to set the image directly in the PHP?

Comment: Decided against that and added classes and your css worked fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is to combine [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/l) and [theme_image()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/theme_image):

```
print l(theme_image(array('path' => 'edit_button.png', 'attributes' => array('title' => t('Edit')))), 'node/' . $node->nid . '/webform/components/' . $cid, array('query' => drupal_get_destination(), 'html' => TRUE));
```

You should also use [drupal_get_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/drupal_get_path) to prefix the path of your image.
This way you will fully apply to the Drupal Coding standards, and make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I implemented:

```
list($nodeImage) = field_get_items('node', $node, 'uc_product_image');

$style_array = array('path' => $nodeImage['uri'], 'style_name' => 'MY_IMAGE_STYLE');

$render_node_image = theme('image_style', $style_array);   
$render_node_image_WITH_LINK = l($render_node_image, 'node/' . $node->nid, array('html' => TRUE));

print $render_node_image_WITH_LINK
```